# Today Extension doesnt appear in Notification Center

Tags: ios, ios8-today-widget

I added Today Extansion to my project (2 years old) but it doesnt apear in Notification Center. When adding this tutorial helped mine: http://www.raywenderlich.com/83809/ios-8-today-extension-tutorial

My project have two targets (Dev, Production). Im using Xcode 6.1 and cocopoads. When I run TodayExt scheme:

http://pl.tinypic.com/r/2146zhk/8

and its stuck.

When Im creating new Xcode project everything works fine.

What should I check in my project?

Answer (score 0):

When creating an extension, you must run your parent app through Xcode at least once for your extension to appear. Once you've done this, you should be able to run the extension scheme without problem.

Comment: Thanks for replay, but it doesnt work. What is more I dont need to run parent application when im creating new Xcode project. I think the problem is in my bulid settings in my main project, but i dont know whitch one it is.